# What's the best way to re-run a const-declared function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, constants

New to ES6 here. I have a function declared "inside" a constant:

```
const requestData = https.request(source, function (res) {
   ...
   <function code>
   ...
});
```

I need to re-run this periodically. What's the best way to do it? Simply calling requestData() is throwing 'Type Error' messages. Thanks!

Comment: It’s not a function it’s a call to a function whose result is stored in `requestData`.

Comment: Declare/assign it in the scope you want to use it.

Comment: @remeus— the `function (res) { /* code */ }` part is a [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). I guess that's what the OP wants to call again.

Comment: Thanks, @RobG. I marked your reply as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to *https.request* is a function reference that is called with a single parameter, the result of the request.

If the function is created by a function expression in the call as in the OP, then you can't reference it from any scope other than within the function itself, and only then if it's been given a name.

If you want to call the function separately, you need to declare/assign it first in the scope you want to call it, then use it in the call. E.g. using an arrow function:

```
const myCallback = (res) => {
   ...
   <function code>
   ...
}

const requestData = https.request(source, myCallback);

myCallback( whatever );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code inside a function.

```
function fn(source){
    https.request(source, function (res) {
        // ...
    });
}
fn(someSource);
```